# how do I plot a graph with range as it's index?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Data on which I am trying to plot a graph

[image: Data on which I am trying to plot a graph]

I am trying to plot the graph with ranges mentioned in the table as x values and the count as its y axis, which I am not able to do with bar graph or histogram.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get discrete values where to plot the bars, then you can change the labels to display the range you want. In this case, the `mean` of your range would make sense.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df['x_ticks'], df['Count'], width=8) #you can play around with the width as you like
ax.set_xticks(df['x_ticks'])
ax.set_xticklabels([f"{tup[0]}-{tup[1]}" for tup in df['Age']]) # f-string for presentation of your x-labels
```

Plot:

[image]

Input data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Age' : [(x,x+10) for x in range(0,90,10)],
    'Count': [64,115,407,154,86,42,16,5,0]
})
df['x_ticks'] = df['Age'].apply(np.mean)
print(df)
```

```
        Age  Count  x_ticks
0   (0, 10)     64      5.0
1  (10, 20)    115     15.0
2  (20, 30)    407     25.0
3  (30, 40)    154     35.0
4  (40, 50)     86     45.0
5  (50, 60)     42     55.0
6  (60, 70)     16     65.0
7  (70, 80)      5     75.0
8  (80, 90)      0     85.0
```